# Ubuntu DHCP central server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wifi, dhcp

I have very little experience on this so I am  asking to see if this is even possible. I have 4 different ADSL connections that each one is connected to one access point so I have 4 total different lans. I provide free hotspot on each access point (same SSID) and the user roaming from one access point to the other as they move into the area. (The area is a long road and the distance beetween each AP is about 100m).
Anyway i saw on the modems the option for dhcp relay so I am asking this.

Can I build a central server (internet accessable) with ubuntu and dhcp server on it and setup the modems to use this as DHCP server? So the user keep the same IP as it moves from one AP to the other. All adsl modems will have the same IP so the gateway will remain same for all networks. I dont know if this is good so I am asking this question just to tell me what is the best way? To build a central server or to leave each modem act as dhcp server

Because my English are not very well I hope you understand my question

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean you have 4 differents networks bridged together somehow or you really have 4 independent ADSL modems?

Comment: 4 independent ADSL modems!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done, but I don't know if it will provide any benefit to you:

User comes online from AP1, DHCP discover is received by the modem and relayed to the DHCP server, response is sent back and the user receives and binds to IP.

User crosses the threshold and changes to AP2.  Because the media has changed, the user will re-discover and perform the DHCP process again.  They will most likely be allocated the same address again (presuming the lease hasn't expired or been administratively removed), but you're still re-binding the IP.  Because you are re-binding the IP on the User, any open TCP connections would likely be severed.

I think that this is what you're trying to avoid by allocating the same address across all devices, but please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly! But i was hoping the things to was faster. Let say if i have two APs on the same modem the roaming from one AP to the other happens instanly and the user stays without internet for 1 second. If this 2 APs are on different ADSL connections when the user roams from the one to the other this 1 second become 5 becuase it needs to get a new Ip etc etc. I was hoping that a central DHCP server resolve me this problem but i think that you are right and its not possible

Comment: This is a common problem.  Believe it or not, mobile internet (WCDMA/3G/3G) is much the same way.  As you change from GSN to GSN, you get allocated different addresses from the different gateways and these types of interruptions occur.

Comment: Hi Tyler! Is it possible for you and do you have the knowlege to let me know how to create a remote ubuntu relay server? I want to try some things but first of all i dont know what to do to setup the server and let each modem know that the relay server is on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx internet IP of that server! For now i have the server up and running with ubuntu lts 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: I was under the impression from your initial post that you found the configuration option on the modems to configure the DHCP relay address?  So is this more of a modem configuration question, or DHCP configuration question?

Comment: Modems gives me the option to setup the ip of my "DHCP relay server" so I think the first thing i have to do is to create one under ubuntu and when there are all ready to put the ip of the server to the modems

Comment: Yes, this will relay all the broadcast DHCP traffic from the LAN (port 67/udp) to the specified server as unicast.